# Getting PHP fatal errors in vTiger while logging from a normal users

Tags: php, apache-httpd

I am getting the error below and notices in Apache logs when I am trying to login with any normal user on vTiger although admin user is working fine and able to see everything as expected.

Below are the errors:

```
[Mon Aug 29 13:49:54 2011] [error] [client 52.165.191.160] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  search in /var/www/html/crm/include/utils/utils.php on line 996, referer: website://crm.abc.com/crm/index.php?module=Settings&action=OrgSharingDetailView&parenttab=Settings
[Mon Aug 29 13:49:54 2011] [error] [client 52.165.191.160] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  file in /var/www/html/crm/include/utils/utils.php on line 1000, referer: website://crm.abc.com/crm/index.php?module=Settings&action=OrgSharingDetailView&parenttab=Settings
[Mon Aug 29 13:49:54 2011] [error] [client 52.165.191.160] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  search in /var/www/html/crm/include/utils/utils.php on line 996, referer: website://crm.abc.com/crm/index.php?module=Settings&action=OrgSharingDetailView&parenttab=Settings
[Mon Aug 29 13:49:54 2011] [error] [client 52.165.191.160] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  file in /var/www/html/crm/include/utils/utils.php on line 1000, referer: website://crm.abc.com/crm/index.php?module=Settings&action=OrgSharingDetailView&parenttab=Settings
[Mon Aug 29 13:49:54 2011] [error] [client 52.165.191.160] PHP Warning:  require(user_privileges/user_privileges_81.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/crm/modules/Users/CreateUserPrivilegeFile.php on line 114, referer: website://crm.abc.com/crm/index.php?module=Settings&action=OrgSharingDetailView&parenttab=Settings
[Mon Aug 29 13:49:54 2011] [error] [client 52.165.191.160] PHP Fatal error:  require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'user_privileges/user_privileges_81.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/crm/include/htmlpurifier/library:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/crm/modules/Users/CreateUserPrivilegeFile.php on line 114, referer: website://crm.abc.com/crm/index.php?module=Settings&action=OrgSharingDetailView&parenttab=Settings
[Mon Aug 29 13:49:54 2011] [error] [client 52.165.191.160] File does not exist: /var/www/html/favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors you are seeing are quite specific to vTiger - so this rather off-topic here.

The amount of noise in the log files does not fill me with confidence about the quality of the product. But the reason it is failing is the second last entry you posted. There is a problem with the file 'user_privileges/user_privileges_81.php' - either the webserver uid cannot read from the directory where it is located, you never installed the file, or it's not on your include path.